# Footer covers content

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to build my personal webpage but simply cant manage to make my footer not cover the two buttons.
This problem only occurs on my laptop. As soon as I switch to my external monitor, the two buttons arent covered anymore.
I have tried inserting html{overflow-y: scroll;} to my css but it doesnt seem to work :(
Any help would be awesome! Thank you.

**HTML:**

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.logo {
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}

.navbar ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  transition: .2s;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.wrapper .center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
}

.center h1 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center h2 {
  color: black;
  font-size: 70px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 885px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.center .buttons {
  margin: 35px 280px;
}

.buttons button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  border: 1px solid #4b79b4;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.buttons .btn {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.buttons button:hover {
  background: #4b79b4;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #808080;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: black;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-content h3 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 3rem;
}

.footer-content p {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0 3rem 0;
}

.socials li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.socials a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightsteelblue;
}

.socials a i {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  transition: color .4s ease;
}

.socials a:hover i {
  color: #4b79b4;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background-color: #737373;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-bottom p {
  font-size: 14px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.footer-bottom span {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en ">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Moritz </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- BEGIN NAVBAR -->
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">CV</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Favourites</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- END NAVBAR -->

    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
    <div class="center">
      <h1>Hi, I'm Moritz.</h1>
      <h2>I'm a student.</h2>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Explore more</button>
        <button class="btn">Contact me</button>
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTENT -->
    </div>

    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER -->
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-content">
        <h3>Moritz </h3>
        <p>Thank you for browsing. I hope to hear from you soon!</p>
        <ul class="socials">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p> Copyright &copy; 2021 Moritz </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- END FOOTER -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately it did not change the situation on my laptop :(

Comment: I did the edit on your question just to "show what you have" to start with,

Answer (score 0):

What you describe kind of feels like a grid to me using three "rows", one for the "navbar", one for the "content" and one for the "footer" such as:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
```

Now given that we can put the containers for the rows in a wrapper `.wrapper`
Then we tall it which "row" each of the sections belongs in.  `grid-row: 2/2;` for the content for example in row 2 (start and end)

I took a good bit of liberty with your CSS (it is still a "lot" just for this) specifically, I added borders to show where things are - you will want to remove those but I did it to illustrate where is "is" in the flow.
This is by no means "perfect" but just a very quick place to build from.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700&display=swap');
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: solid orange 3px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: lime 4px dashed;
}

.navbar-container {
  border: red 4px solid;
  grid-row: 1/1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  margin: 0rem;
}

.content-container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  grid-row: 2/2;
  border: blue 1px solid;
}

.footer-container {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  border: cyan 1px solid;
}

.footer-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.footer-bottom {
  grid-row: 3/3;
  align-text: center;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: dashed blue 1px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #808080;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.navbar>.logo {
  width: 140px;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.wrapper .center {
  user-select: none;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.buttons button {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.buttons button {
  flex: auto;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
  border: 1px solid #4b79b4;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.buttons button:hover {
  background: #4b79b4;
}

.socials {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: middle;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socials li {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.footer-bottom {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  background-color: #737373;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: .4;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en ">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Moritz </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-container">
      <img class="logo" src="logo.png">
      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li> <a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">CV</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Favourites</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="center content-container">
      <h1>Hi, I'm Moritz.</h1>
      <h2>I'm a student.</h2>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button>Explore more</button>
        <button class="btn">Contact me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer-container">
      <div class="footer-content">
        <h3>Moritz </h3>
        <p>Thank you for browsing. I hope to hear from you soon!</p>
        <ul class="socials">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-bottom">
        <p> Copyright &copy; 2021 Moritz </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```